# bject disappearing while rotating in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have this weird problem in which the object that I'm trying to rotate just suddenly disappears. The way I am looking to rotate the object is with a keypress, which turns a global variable `rotateAnimation` to true. When the variable `rotateAnimation` is false, the object is visible, but once it's true the object disappears.

Here is the code:

```cpp
bool rotateAnimation = false;
bool moveAnimation = false;
int moveDirX = 1, moveDirY = 1;


void DrawSpiral(int x, int y)
{
    float tx, ty;
    float i;
    float a = 0, b = 0;

    glPointSize(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 0.025)
    {
        a = a + .05;
        b = b + .05;
        tx = x + b * cos(i);
        ty = y + a * sin(i);
        glVertex2f(tx, ty);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void DrawSquare(int x, int y, int size)
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(x - size, y);
    glVertex2f(x - size, y - size);
    glVertex2f(x, y - size);

    glEnd();
}

void DrawPolygon(int x, int y)
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(x - 25, y - 25);
    glVertex2f(x - 15, y - 53);
    glVertex2f(x + 15, y - 53);
    glVertex2f(x + 25, y - 25);

    glEnd();
}

void init()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Since I want to do rotation in 2D

    glLoadIdentity();

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    gluOrtho2D(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
}


void Keypress(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {

    case 'm':
        moveAnimation = !moveAnimation;
        break;

    case 'o':
        rotateAnimation = !rotateAnimation;
        break;
    }
}


void Display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    staticScene(); // Some other drawings that should always be there on the screen

    glPushMatrix();
    if (rotateAnimation)
    {
        glRotatef(60, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPointSize(2);

    if (shape == "square")
        DrawSquare(X, Y, 40);
    else if (shape == "polygon")
        DrawPolygon(X, Y);
    else if (shape == "spiral")
        DrawSpiral(X, Y);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / 60, timer, 0);

    if (moveAnimation)
    {
        int dx = 2, dy = 2;

        if (X - dx < 0) // Add from X
            X += dx, moveDirX = 1;
        else if (X + dx > drawingWindow[0].first) // Subtract to X
            X -= dx, moveDirX = -1;
        else
            X += (dx * moveDirX);

        if (Y - dy < drawingWindow[2].second) // Add from Y
            Y += dy, moveDirY = 1;
        else if (Y + dy > drawingWindow[0].second) // Subtract to Y
            Y -= dy, moveDirY = -1;
        else
            Y += (dy * moveDirY);
    }
}
```

When `rotateAnimation` is false:

[image]

When `rotateAnimation` is true:

[image]

**EDIT**: I tried to scale the object too, but the same thing happens, when the toggle is on the object disappears, and when off it appears. One thing I noted is that when I comment out the `TimerFunc` then nothing happens. Neither does the object `scale` or `rotate` depending on what is toggled on.

Comment: I think It is not disapparing but it must have been rotated out of the viewport. You should chekc your roation matrix and try to rotate it around its axis to see if that is working or not.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, since the viewport width and height is same as the window width and height.

Answer (score 0):

***Edited:*** You didn't switch the matrix mode to `GL_MODELVIEW`.

```c
void init()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Since I want to do rotation in 2D

    glLoadIdentity();

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    gluOrtho2D(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //<--here
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to add all the draw functions. Could you check once?

Comment: The same happens even with `glRotatef(60, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. I had set that to 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 just for testing purposes

Comment: I am also using the timer function for which I updated the code above.